# SQL(query) error or missing database when create database from physical copy of sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a database in sqlite studio which I'm importing in to my android app. SQLite helper code is as below :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


String DB_PATH = null;
private static String DB_NAME = "mydatabases";
private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 21);
    this.myContext = context;
    this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";

    Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
}



@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){}

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion){
        try {
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to fetch data from database, below is code to retrieve data in activity load:

onActivityCreated code :

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final ArrayList<String> strArary;
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    c = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM categories",null) ; // myDbHelper.query("categories",null,null,null,null,null,null);

 if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            strArary1.add(c.getString(0));
            strArary.add(c.getString(1));

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Given code raise some error as mention in question title.

Please help me to resolve issue.

Comment: Consider using [sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) instead.

Comment: I think you need to do this before `onCreate` as `onCreate` is called only if the file doesn't exist, in which case the database file is created and then the code in `onCreate` is called.

Answer (score -1):

That is my class and works fine for me:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DataBase_Name = "yourdb";
    private static final int DataBase_Version = 3;
    private static final String Path ="/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
    public Cursor cursor;
    protected Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase DB;
    String url;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DataBase_Name, null, DataBase_Version);
        this.context = context;

        try {
            OpenDataBase();
            Close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    private void CopyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myinput = context.getAssets().open(DataBase_Name);
        String output = Path + DataBase_Name;

        OutputStream myoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        try {
            while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                myoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myoutputstream.flush();
            myoutputstream.close();
            myinput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    protected boolean ChekDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase exist = null;
        try {
            String DBPath = Path + DataBase_Name;
            exist = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            if (DataBase_Version > exist.getVersion()) {
                exist.close();
                CopyDataBase();
                exist = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                exist.setVersion(DataBase_Version);
                Util.saveDataToShared(context, "sync", "fixedInserted", "");
            }


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (exist != null) {
            exist.close();
        }
        return exist != null ? true : false;

    }

    private void OpenDataBase() throws SQLDataException {

        if (ChekDB()) {

            String DBPath = Path + DataBase_Name;
            DB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } else {
            this.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                CopyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    }

    public Cursor Select(String Query) {

        try {
            OpenDataBase();
            cursor = DB.rawQuery(Query, null);
        } catch (SQLDataException e) {
            if (e!=null&&e.getMessage()!=null)
                Log.e("Handler - Select :",e.getMessage());
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    /**
     * @param tableName
     * @param contentValues
     * @param whereClause
     * @param args
     * @return Rows Effected
     */
    protected int update(String tableName, ContentValues contentValues, String whereClause, String[] args) {
        try {
            OpenDataBase();
        } catch (SQLDataException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        int result = DB.update(tableName, contentValues, whereClause, null);
        DB.close();
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param tableName
     * @param whereClause
     * @param args
     * @return Rows Effected
     */
    protected int delete(String tableName, String whereClause, String[] args) {
        try {
            OpenDataBase();
        } catch (SQLDataException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        int result = DB.delete(tableName, whereClause, args);
        DB.close();
        return result;
    }

    protected long insert(String Table_Name, ContentValues V) {
        long rowid = -1;
        try {
            OpenDataBase();
            rowid = DB.insert(Table_Name, null, V);
            System.out.println(rowid);
            DB.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e!=null&&e.getMessage()!=null)
              Log.e("Inserting to Table "+Table_Name,e.getMessage());
            DB.close();
        }
        return rowid;
    }

    protected void ExecuteQuery(String Q) {
        try {
            OpenDataBase();
            DB.execSQL(Q);
            DB.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ExecuteQuery " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void Close() {
        if (DB != null)
            DB.close();
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
            cursor.close();
    }

    public void WhenUpGrade() {
        try {
            String assetPath = context.getAssets().toString() + "/" + DataBase_Name;
            SQLiteDatabase assetDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(assetPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            SQLiteDatabase oldDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path + DataBase_Name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            Log.d("", assetDB != null ? "" : "");
            Log.d("", oldDB != null ? "" : "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null)
                Log.e("upgradingDB", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Similar kind of code also works for me, But when you want to change database or tables in production environment, it will not work, User must have to unistall app to get reflaction of new changes.

Comment: no i updated it to check on database version and if version more than the current it will recopy database